Skorohod integration by parts of an adapted process.
I'm trying to evaluate $\int_0^T W(t)\,\delta W(t)$ using the integration by parts formula using the Malliavin Derivative $$F \int_0^T u(t) \,\delta W(t) = \int_0^T F u(t)\,\delta W(t) + \int_0^T u(t) D_t F\, dt$$
taking F = W(t) and u(t) = 1. Because W(t) is $\mathcal{F}_t$ - adapted the Skorohod integral should coincide with the Itô integral yielding $\int_0^T W(t)\,\delta W(t) = \int_0^T W(t)\,d W(t) = \frac{1}{2}W^2(T) - \frac{1}{2} T$ but I cannot get there. This is my best try at the moment.
$$W(t) \int_0^T 1 \,\delta W(t) = \int_0^T W(t) (1)\,\delta W(t) + \int_0^T (1) D_t W(t)\, dt\\
W(t) W(T) = \int_0^T W(t)\,\delta W(t) + \int_0^T  \chi_{[0, t]}(t)\, dt\\
\int_0^T W(t)\,\delta W(t)  =  W(t) W(T) -  t\\$$
Where $D_t W(t) = D_t \int_0^T \chi_{[0, t]}(t_1)\,dW(t_1) = \chi_{[0, t]}(t)$. What am I missing?
